# elasticsearch not returning text when entered partial word

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I have my analyzers set like this:

```
"analyzer": {
    "edgeNgram_autocomplete": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": ["lowercase", "autocomplete"]
    },                
    "full_name": {
        "filter":["standard","lowercase","asciifolding"],
        "type":"custom",
        "tokenizer":"standard"
    }
```

My filter:

```
"filter": {
    "autocomplete": {
        "type": "edgeNGram",
        "side":"front",
        "min_gram": 1,
        "max_gram": 50
    }
```

Name field analyzer:

```
"textbox": {
    "_parent": {
        "type": "document"
    },            
    "properties": {
        "text": {
            "fields": {
                "text": {
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"full_name"
                },
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index_analyzer": "edgeNgram_autocomplete",
                    "search_analyzer": "full_name",
                    "analyzer": "full_name"
                }
            },
            "type":"multi_field"
        }
    }
}
```

Put all together, makes up my mapping for docstore index:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/docstore
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "edgeNgram_autocomplete": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "autocomplete"]
                },                
                "full_name": {
                   "filter":["standard","lowercase","asciifolding"],
                   "type":"custom",
                   "tokenizer":"standard"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "side":"front",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 50
                }           }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "space": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        "document": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "space"
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        "textbox": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "document"
            },            
            "properties": {
                "bbox": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "text": {
                    "fields": {
                        "text": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "analyzer":"full_name"
                        },
                        "autocomplete": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index_analyzer": "edgeNgram_autocomplete",
                            "search_analyzer": "full_name",
                            "analyzer":"full_name"
                        }
                    },
                    "type":"multi_field"
                }
            }
        },
        "entity": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "document"
            },
            "properties": {
                "bbox": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add a space to hold all docs:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/docstore/space
{
    "name": "Space 1"
}
```

[image: mapping]

When user enters word: `proj`

this should return, all text:

- SampleProject
- Sample Project
- Project Name
- myProjectname
- firstProjectName
- my ProjectName

But it returns nothing.

My query:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/docstore/textbox/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text": "proj"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "has_parent": {
            "type": "document",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "name": "1-a1-1001.pdf"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I search by `project`, I get:

```
{ "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 2,
        "max_score": 3.0133555,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "docstore",
                "_type": "textbox",
                "_id": "AVRuV2d_f4y6IKuxK35g",
                "_score": 3.0133555,
                "_routing": "AVRuVvtLf4y6IKuxK33f",
                "_parent": "AVRuV2cMf4y6IKuxK33g",
                "_source": {
                    "bbox": [
                        8750,
                        5362,
                        9291,
                        5445
                    ],
                    "text": [
                        "Sample Project"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "docstore",
                "_type": "textbox",
                "_id": "AVRuV2d_f4y6IKuxK35Y",
                "_score": 2.4106843,
                "_routing": "AVRuVvtLf4y6IKuxK33f",
                "_parent": "AVRuV2cMf4y6IKuxK33g",
                "_source": {
                    "bbox": [
                        8645,
                        5170,
                        9070,
                        5220
                    ],
                    "text": [
                        "Project Name and Address"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Maybe my edgengram is not suited for this?
I am saying:

```
side":"front"
```

Should I do it differently?

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the autocomplete indexing analyzer field name.

Change:

```
"index_analyzer": "edgeNgram_autocomplete"
```

To:

```
"analyzer": "edgeNgram_autocomplete"
```

And also search like (@Andrei Stefan) showed in his answer:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/docstore/textbox/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "text.autocomplete": "proj"
        }
    }
}
```

And it will work as expected!

I have tested your configuration on `Elasticsearch 2.3`

By the way, type `multi_field` is [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html).

Hope I have managed to help :)

Comment: Yes, it is replaced by `string`. For instance, in your example the text field would look like:    `"text": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "full_name",
      "fields": {
         "autocomplete": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "edgeNgram_autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "full_name"
         }
      }
   }`

Answer (score 1):

Your query should actually try to match on `text.autocomplete` and not `text`:

```
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text.autocomplete": "proj"
    }
  }
```

Comment: .... ok, the run the following the provide the result: `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/docstore/textbox/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "project"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "document",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "name": "1-a1-1001.pdf"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fielddata_fields": ["text.autocomplete","text"]
}'`

Comment: it didn't do anything